# Will the cart steer to the left/right by itself in this design?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors, bearings, electric-vehicles

I'm trying to retrofit a [pull cart](https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/edc7e5b39855f7a486aeb53414e7cb6bbf2ca3e3/0_211_5184_3110/master/5184.jpg?width=300&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=3d53a0037230b597b24cd53e2b653091) with electric motor. So, one wheel will have an electric hub motor and it is connected to a rotating shaft to the other non-powered wheel. The driveshaft is connected to the undercarriage of the cart via [pillow block bearing](https://res.cloudinary.com/rsc/image/upload/b_rgb:FFFFFF,c_pad,dpr_1.0,f_auto,h_843,q_auto,w_1500/c_pad,h_843,w_1500/F7508977-01?pgw=1&pgwact=1).

As the powered wheel rotates, the other wheel follows and rotates, that's the idea.

Steering should be done by the user with their hands/arms, not by the motors.

I wonder if the cart will slowly steer unwantedly to the left and right, since only one motor is attached to only one wheel?

P/S: I can't have two motors at two wheels because if both are not completely in sync (which is hard to achieve), the cart will steer to the left or right ny itself (imagine how a a tank steers). I will also have a switch to turn on/off the motor and PAS sensor. I will figure out the speed control issue in another post.

Comment: The OP has already asked a related question [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51111/could-radial-bearings-with-brackets-hold-the-weight-and-load-of-a-large-cart/51113#51113) and is considering an e-bike wheel hub motor which requires the axle to be locked in position (as on a motorised bicycle). A rotating axle from one wheel to the other is not possible with this arrangement as has already been explained.

Comment: A PAS sensor is a Pedal Assist Sensor. Since your cart doesn't have pedals it is difficult to know how you intend to incorporate it. See https://evelo.com/blogs/learn/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cadence-sensor-and-a-torque-sensor-on-an-electric-bike for more.

Comment: @Transistor I aim to place the PAS near the hub. So, when the cart is pulled, the sensor should sense the motion and fires up the motor. But should I use cadence or torque sensor?

Comment: "*... the sensor should sense the motion and fires up the motor.*" The PAS is designed to switch off the motor when pedaling stops. If you attach it to the wheel then once the motor starts the PAS will force it to keep running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only 1 wheel is driven, and the other can spin freely, yes it will want to cut aggressively towards the opposite side from the wheel.