# How to slow down an electric motor for pull cart?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors, gears, bicycles

I'm trying to retrofit an electric motor (such as [this](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/3000W-48V-60V-72V-84V-96V_1600103779994.html?spm=a2700.details.0.0.6777758443el7c)) to a pull cart as depicted below. I got most things figured out except for how to slow down the motor to a pedestrian speed.

Could I slow it down by reducing the amperes? Or must I use a lower gear ratio?

[image]

Comment: So did you check out the pedal assist as per your post and the comments here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/51117/10902

Comment: And the answer here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/51115/10902

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you for reminding me. I missed it but I just replied them.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid a gearbox, which is understandable since gearboxes are expensive, you just use a chain drive or a belt. You need to attach a motor to each wheel anyways and it's unlikely that the motor can support the weight of the cart on its own shaft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific motor that you linked is a [BLDC motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor) and requires a controller. The multitude of wires coming out is a tell.

This controller will be what will regulate the speed. By turning on and off certain coils in a rythm.

To set the speed to your liking you will need to program the controller to your needs.

Comment: When you said program the controller, how difficult will that be? Is the controller meant to be reprogrammed and comes with a manual for this? I mean are most are?

Comment: depends on the controller you get. Some are very locked off, and some let you rewrite the entire code.

Comment: @ratib90486 You will need to buy a brushless motor controller (also known as ESC - electronic speed controller) to use this motor. A brushless motor won't spin if you just plug it into a power source. It needs the electronics.